# How to effectively call properties in another class - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I am a beginner with Objective-C and iOS development, and I can't figure out how to send data from one class to another without it returning **null** or in this case "0.0000"

I'll give the code I have-

In ClassA.h I have two properties

```
@interface ClassA : UIView

// This is public property!
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat touchPointX;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat touchPointY;

// My test getters
- (CGFloat) touchLocationX;
- (CGFloat) touchLocationY;

@end;
```

Then in ClassA.m I implement these.

```
@implementation ClassA

- (void)baseInit {
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:self.frame];
    if (self) {
        [self baseInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        [self baseInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];

        // Save the touch locations in our local variables.
        self.touchPointX = touchLocation.x;
        self.touchPointY = touchLocation.y;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

- (CGFloat) touchLocationX {
    return self.touchPointX;
}

- (CGFloat) touchLocationY {
    return self.touchPointY;
}

@end
```

Then I try to log the values in AppDelegate using some code I found on here

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, copy) ClassA *touchLocationX;
@property (nonatomic, copy) ClassA *touchLocationY;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
                                             (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
        NSLog(@"(%@, %@)", _touchLocationX, _touchLocationY");

    });

    return YES;
}
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to do something like:

```
ClassA * myView = [[ClassA alloc] init];
myView = [myViewController theUIViewForClassA];
```

In the long run all I want is the properties to return the correct values

Comment: honestly several things in your code are very strange. I think you should start over again learning Objective-C with a good resource.

Comment: Well what is wrong with it? The guy who deleted his answer told me the Getters were useless, which I can understand I should have just `@synthesized` but everything I have done so far has worked, I just can't pass those variable values to another class...

Comment: There is absolutely no need to have views in the app delegate. Why dos you dispatch the NSLog call? You call a View subclass `touchLocationX` that has the properties `touchPointX` & `touchPointY`. same with a view object `touchLocationX ` — wtf? In `touchesMoved:withEvents:` you reset the ivars numerous times. This all makes no sense at all. Just because it compiles doesn't make it right.

Comment: @vikingosegundo What I think they are trying to do is send the two variables `touchLocationX` and `touchLocationY` to that Async thread in AppDelegate, then print them out. Maybe?

Comment: @Saturisk That was the objective. I just can't figure out how to send the touchLocation variables to another class so I can access them.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways in which data can be shared across an application.

In your example, you want to "send" touchpoints from ClassA to some other class, in this case the AppDelegate, which is fine as it demonstrates how this can work with other classes.

To accomplish this, several design patterns come to mind: [**Delegate Protocol**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html), [**Notifications**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html) or **Singleton**.

I'll use the example of a singelton for convenience, because it allows us to use your AppDelegate, which is already a singleton, so this example can closely resemble your existing code.

Note that a singleton design pattern is one in which a singleton class is instantiated only once, whose methods and properties can be accessed by other classes throughout the application.

Example:

**AppDelegate.h**

*Add a method for receiving touch events*

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
- (void) notifyTouchEvents:(CGFloat)touchX :(CGFloat)touchY;
@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

*Implement the method*

```
@implementation AppDelegate

// Method for receiving touch event data from another class
- (void) notifyTouchEvents:(CGFloat)touchX :(CGFloat)touchY
{
    NSLog(@"touchX: %f, touchY: %f", touchX, touchY);
}
```

**ClassA.h**

*Import the App Delegate*

Note: This example doesn't require `touchPointX` and `touchPointY` properties.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat touchPointX;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat touchPointY;
@end
```

**ClassA.m**

*Access the AppDelegate touch notification method during touch events*

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

        // Access the AppDelegate singleton and notification method
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate notifyTouchEvents:touchLocation.x :touchLocation.y];
    }
}


@end
```

In practice, you may find that a combination of using NSNotificationCenter and a Singleton can works best. Search around for more information on using delegates and singletons with Objective C.